# Transparency lost when enabling colors on Android OpenGL

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, samsung-mobile

I am programming a tunnel animation in Android OpenGL. It has transparent textures with shifting colors. The transparency works every time when I don't enable the colors. The problem is that the transparency stops to work sometimes when I enable colors with  gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY).

I started the animation 30 times and the transparency worked only on 62% of those cases. The transparency were lost in 38% of those cases. I tested on Samsung S6 and Samsung Tab2. How can I adjust my code, so the transparency works every time?

```
gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_ALPHA_TEST);

gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);

gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

gl.glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, colorBuffer);

gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBufferLT44);

gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, texBufferLT1);

// opaque objects rendered first:

drawOpaqueObjs(gl, rotationSpeed, myFusedOrientation);

drawTransparentObjs(gl, rotationSpeed, myFusedOrientation);
```

Comment: You're enabling the alpha test; are you calling `glAlphaFunc`? If so, with what parameters?

Comment: Thanks, I added this now: gl.glAlphaFunc(GL10.GL_ALWAYS, 0f);

Comment: I used these arguments to get the alpha testing to pass and the fragment to be drawn everytime. It is however still the same problem. I also tested glAlphaFunc(GL_GREATER, 0.1f); The specification says "If the value passes the comparison, the incoming fragment is drawn". So I assume that when the alpha is lost, it is because either the stencil, alpha or depth buffer tests fails? Do you have any idea how I can fix this, so alpha is shown every time? I assume that I must be in RGBA mode, because the alpha is shown  in 70% of the cases?